# How to combine 3 xsl transformations in one?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have 3 xsl transformations which, when run seperatedly, work fine but I'd like all 3 in one xsl for simplicity.

Input xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SHPMNT05>
   <IDOC BEGIN="1">
      <EDI_DC40 SEGMENT="1">
         <TABNAM>EDI_DC40</TABNAM>
      </EDI_DC40>
      <E1EDT20 SEGMENT="1">
         <TKNUM>0000287203</TKNUM>
         <E1EDK33 SEGMENT="1">
            <TSNUM>0001</TSNUM>
            <E1EDT44 SEGMENT="1">
               <QUALI>001</QUALI>
            </E1EDT44>
            <E1EDT44 SEGMENT="1">
               <QUALI>002</QUALI>
               <ABLAD>1</ABLAD>
            </E1EDT44>
            <E1EDT01 SEGMENT="1">
               <VBELN>0081018666</VBELN>
            </E1EDT01>
            <E1EDT01 SEGMENT="1">
               <VBELN>0081018667</VBELN>
            </E1EDT01>
            <E1EDT01 SEGMENT="1">
               <VBELN>0081018668</VBELN>
            </E1EDT01>
         </E1EDK33>
         <E1EDK33 SEGMENT="1">
            <TSNUM>0002</TSNUM>
            <E1EDT44 SEGMENT="1">
               <QUALI>001</QUALI>
            </E1EDT44>
            <E1EDT44 SEGMENT="1">
               <QUALI>002</QUALI>
               <ABLAD>2</ABLAD>
            </E1EDT44>
            <E1EDT01 SEGMENT="1">
               <VBELN>0081018666</VBELN>
            </E1EDT01>
            <E1EDT01 SEGMENT="1">
               <VBELN>0081018668</VBELN>
            </E1EDT01>
         </E1EDK33>
         <E1EDK33 SEGMENT="1">
            <TSNUM>0002</TSNUM>
            <E1EDT44 SEGMENT="1">
               <QUALI>001</QUALI>
            </E1EDT44>
            <E1EDT44 SEGMENT="1">
               <QUALI>002</QUALI>
               <ABLAD>3</ABLAD>
            </E1EDT44>
            <E1EDT01 SEGMENT="1">
               <VBELN>0081018666</VBELN>
            </E1EDT01>            
         </E1EDK33>
         <E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
            <VBELN>0081018666</VBELN>
         </E1EDL20>
         <E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
            <VBELN>0081018667</VBELN>
         </E1EDL20>
         <E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
            <VBELN>0081018668</VBELN>
         </E1EDL20>
      </E1EDT20>
   </IDOC>
</SHPMNT05>
```

Required result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SHPMNT05>
   <IDOC BEGIN="1">
      <EDI_DC40 SEGMENT="1">
         <TABNAM>EDI_DC40</TABNAM>
      </EDI_DC40>
      <E1EDT20 SEGMENT="1">
         <TKNUM>0000287203</TKNUM>
         <E1EDK33 SEGMENT="1">
            <TSNUM>0001</TSNUM>
            <E1EDT44 SEGMENT="1">
               <QUALI>001</QUALI>
            </E1EDT44>
            <E1EDT44 SEGMENT="1">
               <QUALI>002</QUALI>
               <ABLAD>1</ABLAD>
            </E1EDT44>
            <E1EDT01 SEGMENT="1">
               <VBELN>0081018667</VBELN>
            </E1EDT01>
         </E1EDK33>
         <E1EDK33 SEGMENT="1">
            <TSNUM>0002</TSNUM>
            <E1EDT44 SEGMENT="1">
               <QUALI>001</QUALI>
            </E1EDT44>
            <E1EDT44 SEGMENT="1">
               <QUALI>002</QUALI>
               <ABLAD>2</ABLAD>
            </E1EDT44>
            <E1EDT01 SEGMENT="1">
               <VBELN>0081018668</VBELN>
            </E1EDT01>
         </E1EDK33>
         <E1EDK33 SEGMENT="1">
            <TSNUM>0002</TSNUM>
            <E1EDT44 SEGMENT="1">
               <QUALI>001</QUALI>
            </E1EDT44>
            <E1EDT44 SEGMENT="1">
               <QUALI>002</QUALI>
               <ABLAD>3</ABLAD>
            </E1EDT44>
            <E1EDT01 SEGMENT="1">
               <VBELN>0081018666</VBELN>
            </E1EDT01>
         </E1EDK33>
         <E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
            <VBELN>0081018667</VBELN>
            <ABLAD>1</ABLAD>
         </E1EDL20>
         <E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
            <VBELN>0081018668</VBELN>
            <ABLAD>2</ABLAD>
         </E1EDL20>
         <E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
            <VBELN>0081018666</VBELN>
            <ABLAD>3</ABLAD>
         </E1EDL20>
      </E1EDT20>
   </IDOC>
</SHPMNT05>
```

**Steps**

*Step 1:*
Filter out the VBELN elements if they exist in the next sibling

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/SHPMNT05/IDOC/E1EDT20/E1EDK33/E1EDT01[(VBELN= following-sibling::E1EDT01/VBELN) or (VBELN= ../following-sibling::E1EDK33/E1EDT01/VBELN)]"/> 
      
   <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
     </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

*Step 2:*
Use the ABLAD values of the E1EDK33/E1EDT01 elements and add an extra ABLAD element to E1EDL20

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="/SHPMNT05/IDOC/E1EDT20/E1EDL20/VBELN"> 
           <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <xsl:variable name="stopno" select="/SHPMNT05/IDOC/E1EDT20/E1EDK33[E1EDT01/VBELN=current()]/E1EDT44/ABLAD"/>
      
        <ABLAD><xsl:value-of select="$stopno" /></ABLAD> 
      </xsl:template> 
        
   <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
     </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

*Step 3:*
Sort the E1EDL20 elements on the in step 2 newly created E1EDL20\ABLAD elements

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
           
  <xsl:template match="E1EDT20">
      <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        
    <xsl:for-each select="*[not(self::E1EDL20)]">
         <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    
        <xsl:for-each select="E1EDL20">
            <xsl:sort select="ABLAD" data-type="number"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>

      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--  Default Template -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Hope I made myself clear / this is possible :)

Best regards, Mike

Comment: If you want to chain transformations you can do so from a host language (e.g. Java, C#, PHP) or XProc or in XSLT/XPath/XQuery 3 using `fn:transform` (and `fn:fold-left`). Within one XSLT transformation you can, as you use at least XSLT 2, also easily store an intermediary result in a variable and then process that variable further in a separate step, using modes is one helpful feature of XSLT to do that. As for sorting, `xsl:apply-templates` also also `xsl:sort`, so it might be possible to merge your different steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chaining using `fold-left` and `transform` (XPath 3.1, XQuery 3.1):

```
let $xslt1 := document {
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/SHPMNT05/IDOC/E1EDT20/E1EDK33/E1EDT01[(VBELN= following-sibling::E1EDT01/VBELN) or (VBELN= ../following-sibling::E1EDK33/E1EDT01/VBELN)]"/> 
      
   <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
     </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>  
    },
    $xslt2 := document {
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="/SHPMNT05/IDOC/E1EDT20/E1EDL20/VBELN"> 
           <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <xsl:variable name="stopno" select="/SHPMNT05/IDOC/E1EDT20/E1EDK33[E1EDT01/VBELN=current()]/E1EDT44/ABLAD"/>
      
        <ABLAD><xsl:value-of select="$stopno" /></ABLAD> 
      </xsl:template> 
        
   <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
     </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>      
    },
    $xslt3 := document {
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
           
  <xsl:template match="E1EDT20">
      <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        
    <xsl:for-each select="*[not(self::E1EDL20)]">
         <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    
        <xsl:for-each select="E1EDL20">
            <xsl:sort select="ABLAD" data-type="number"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>

      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--  Default Template -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>      
    },
    $xslts := ($xslt1, $xslt2, $xslt3)
return
    fold-left(
      $xslts, 
      ., 
      function($xml, $xslt) { 
        transform( 
          map { 
            'source-node' : $xml, 
            'stylesheet-node' : $xslt 
          }
        )?output
      }
    )
```

Using three transformation steps with three modes in one XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="#all">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="#current"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:variable name="step1">
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="step1"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    
    <xsl:template mode="step1" match="/SHPMNT05/IDOC/E1EDT20/E1EDK33/E1EDT01[(VBELN= following-sibling::E1EDT01/VBELN) or (VBELN= ../following-sibling::E1EDK33/E1EDT01/VBELN)]"/> 
      
    <xsl:template mode="step1" match="text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
    </xsl:template> 
     
     <xsl:variable name="step2">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="$step1/node()" mode="step2"/>
     </xsl:variable>
     
       <xsl:template mode="step2" match="/SHPMNT05/IDOC/E1EDT20/E1EDL20/VBELN"> 
           <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <xsl:variable name="stopno" select="/SHPMNT05/IDOC/E1EDT20/E1EDK33[E1EDT01/VBELN=current()]/E1EDT44/ABLAD"/>
      
        <ABLAD><xsl:value-of select="$stopno" /></ABLAD> 
      </xsl:template> 
        
   <xsl:template mode="step2" match="text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
     </xsl:template> 
     
    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$step2/node()" mode="step3"/>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template mode="step3" match="E1EDT20">
      <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        
    <xsl:for-each select="*[not(self::E1EDL20)]">
         <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    
        <xsl:for-each select="E1EDL20">
            <xsl:sort select="ABLAD" data-type="number"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>

      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Wow, very impressive Martin. You gave me not one but two options to solve it. Option 2 makes more sense to me but that's because of my limited knowledge I guess. Using the node set of the variabele in the next step. Option 1 looks 'interesting' :)
Thanks a lot!

Comment: @MikeDole, the disadvantage of the second approach with the modes is that you have to change the code you originally had to add the modes; the first option allows you to simply chain the existing stylesheets using XPath/XQuery.